# Service provider implementation with Java and SAML 2

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, zk

I'm looking at how to implement a service provider in my JAVA application with SAML 2.0.

I know I need a library, but I can't find one which is up to date and with complete documentation.

My application uses Java 1.8.0_171 and ZK framework, but not Maven.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally I find Spring Security SAML extension the best Java-based SAML SP implementation (thank you Vladimir for providing this!), some other Java-based SAML SP implementation are lacking quite some features and are not even SAMLv2 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with somethin not release yet, there is [Spring plugin for spring security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml) or [Pac4J](https://www.pac4j.org/), wich is realsesd and stable (and has a good community)
For the first one I made an example so i would not forget (https://github.com/Endeios/samlv2app)